# SVG support for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, svg

I am unable to view SVG files in wordpress website. I have tried end up adding mimetypes to .htaccess file as following.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
AddType image/svg+xml .svg
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml

################ Expires Control ################
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

Even i have tried adding the function in functions.php file.

```
function cc_mime_types($mimes) {
  $mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
  return $mimes;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'cc_mime_types');
```

Also I have added mimeTypes to make support in wordpress as

```
$mime_to_ext = apply_filters(
                'getimagesize_mimes_to_exts',
                array(
                    'image/jpeg' => 'jpg',
                    'image/png'  => 'png',
                    'image/gif'  => 'gif',
                    'image/bmp'  => 'bmp',
                    'image/tiff' => 'tif',
                    'image/svg+xml' => 'svg',
                )
            );
```

Comment: did you sure about file address ? and did you try to show another site ?

Comment: My Question is unable to view svg Files in my wordpress website

Comment: By default there is no restriction for svg files. so I said to you to check this .

Comment: can we have your svg file example? upload it some were in wordpress site or a sharing file server.

Answer (score 0):

Add following line of code inside your wp-config.php and it will works.

```
define( 'ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true );
```